# I'm writing a bot for Discord in node.js, and I have no idea how to send a message when it is a specific time, in this case 12:00 pm

Tags: node.js, discord

As the title said, I'm trying to make a discord bot that will send a message at 12:00 pm, but it's throwing out errors. Any help?

```js
bot.on('message', function (user, userID, channelID, message, evt) {
 var date = new Date();
 var curhour = date.getHours()
    if (curhour == '12') {
        var cmd = args[0];
        args = args.splice(1);
        switch(cmd) {
                bot.sendMessage({
                    to: channelID,
                    message: 'MESSAGE SENT AT 12:00 PM'
                });
            break;
            // Just add any case commands if you want to..
         }
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The line "bot.on('message' ....."   Is an event handler that will wake up  and respond only when a message is sent on the server your bot is logged into.   This isn't the best place to put something that should run independently of a message-trigger.

Further up you code, I am guessing you have a line starting with "bot.on('ready'..."   In here you can add an event timer to action whatever you need to do 
at 12:00.    As an example, Something like this wakes up every 5 minutes and runs a cleanup routine.

client.on("ready", () => 
{

```
client.setInterval(() => 
{
    let message = ""; let args = "";
    let cmd = client.commands.get("cleanup");
    if (cmd) cmd.run(client, message, args,db,config);
},300000 )
```

})